# How to create an arbitrary System.Drawing.Color out of a string?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a set of unique strings, and I wish to show them with a color. The strings repeat every here and there so I need the coloring to be consistent, not random.

One approach would be to randomize the color and save it in `Dictionary` or something like that so I can use the same color again.

Another approach would be to come up with a simple algorithm/logic that somehow turns a string into a `System.Drawing.Color`.

However, I'd like to keep it to a set of predefined colors, so that I don't end up having not-so-great colors. Let's call this `List<Color> allowedColors`.

I tried `Convert.ToByte()` and figured I would use the byte for the R, G and B components of `Color`, but that did not work because the conversion does not work that way.

A string is just a simple string `String foo = "bar";`. The relationship between the color and the string does not matter as long as it is consistent, i.e., every time the program is ran it should equal to the same color and the colors should generally be different for each string (and yes there will be duplicate colors because there are more strings than colors and it's not a one-to-one mapping).

Those strings come from a source I do not control. They are unique, but vary. Each time the program is started and if the same string comes up, it should be the same color.

So, I think I'm looking for some sort of string to byte transformation, which when overlaps the byte range starts over, and finally the byte is mapped to RGB and sent to `Color.FromArgb()`.

Comment: Couldn't you at least give one example of the type of string you are talking about? What is the expected relationship between the string and the resulting color?

Comment: The StringConverter class does a pretty good job handling various string formats and recognizing named colors.  Don't make it too arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is simply to assign each string the next available color in your `AvailableColors` list, and save that mapping, the first time you make it, to a dictionary. This can be saved to disk using serialization and and reused in later executions. Here's some (updated) sample code:

```
public Color[] AvailableColors = new Color[] { Colors.Red, Colors.Blue, Colors.Green};         
private int _nextColorIndex = 0;
public Dictionary<string,Color> ColorMappings = new Dictionary<string,Color>();
public Color GetNextColor () 
{
    Color nextColor = AvailableColors[_nextColorIndex];
    _nextColorIndex++;
    if (_nextColorIndex == AvailableColors.Length)
        _nextColorIndex = 0; // Restart colors and reuse.
    return nextColor;
}

public void AssignColor (string myString)
{
    ColorMappings.Add(myString, GetNextColor());
}
```

You'll have to add appropriate handling for when you run out of strings, of course, and maybe concurrency locks around GetNextColor if you're doing it multithreaded, but it's a start.

Comment: Interesting idea. You could implement `AvailableColors` as a queue, and a `GetNextColor` method that returns the next item in the queue and then adds it back to the end of the queue.

Comment: i think you could also use the mod operator, AvailablrColors[_nextColorIndex % AvailableColors.Length] and just keep incrementing the index forever.

Comment: Jim: that's a more elegant solution, but more complex - bringing in yer newfangled classes and whatnot. :)
Aaron: Yeah, that'd work fine. Well, for the first 2,147,483,647 strings, anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set of known unique strings and a set of predefined colors, just use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Color> StringColors = new Dictionary<string, Color>()
{
    {"string1", Colors.Red},
    {"string2", Colors.Green},
    {"string3", Colors.Blue},
};
```

And then it's as simple as:

```
string theString = "string2";
var MyColor = StringColors[theString];
```

Comment: I guess that makes sense, though I need to adapt it a bit since the strings that are unique are still not "hard coded" but come from a source.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list of colors using the FramArgb method:

```
var allowedColors = new List<Color>();
allowedColors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0));
```

Or you can manage a mapping from strings to colors with a dictionary:

```
var colorMap = new Dictionary<string, Color>();
colorMap.Add("red", Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0));
```

In many cases, this would be considered an over engineered solution, but at any rate it's an example of encapsulation in C#:

```
class AppString
{
  private string text;
  private Color color;

  public AppString(string text, Color color)
  {
    this.text = text;
    if(allowedColors.Contains(color))
    {
      this.color = color;
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception("invalid color");
    }
  }

  // This lets you use an AppString most places where you used a regular string.
  public static implicit operator string(AppString appString) 
  { 
        return appString.text;
  }

  // This lets you use an AppString most places where you used a Color.
  public static implicit operator Color(AppString appString) 
  { 
        return appString.color;
  }

  // OR if you don't prefer overloading the implicit cast, a standard pattern
  // is to use a Value property.
  public string Value { get { return this.text; } }
  public Color Color { get { return this.color; } }
}
```